# How can the mutual information be equal to minus conditional entropy?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

I am reading the following paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.06941

The authors in Eq.(8) have obtained a relation which has the mutual information, $i$, in the exponent of the exponential on the RHS of the 1st line. At the end of this equation, it seems mutual information is replaced by minus conditional entropy.

How does such a thing hold and what is the implication of that?

Equation (8):

$$P(X) = \frac{e^{\int^X -\beta (1-e^{i(Y:\tilde{X})})d\tilde{X}}}{Z} \overset{i(Y:X) \to 0}{=} \frac{e^{\int^X \beta i(Y:\tilde{X})d\tilde{X}}}{Z} = \frac{e^{-\beta \int^X S(Y|X=\tilde{X})d\tilde{X}}}{Z},$$

where $\beta$ is some constant, $i$ the mutual information, $S$ conditional entropy, and $Z$ is the normalization constant of the the probability $P$.

Comment: I encourage you to provide a full citation for the paper (title, authors, where published), in addition to the link, so that others with a similar question about the paper can find this web page via search.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/606938/2921, https://mathoverflow.net/q/441859/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/157801/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/606938/2921, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648979/14578, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/752423/24498, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/52531/5038.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.